# DjangoCMS placeholder giving error : "Invalid block tag on line 25: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I have a template below.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load cms_tags menu_tags sekizai_tags snippet_tags %}
<body>
    <!-- header Start -->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar-autohide navbar navbar-white bg-white fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                {% block header %}
                    <h3>THIS IS header</h3>
                    {% placeholder header %}
                {% endblock header %}
    
                {% block navigation %}
                    <h3>This is navigation</h3>
                    {% placeholder navigation %}
                {% endblock navigation %}
            </div>
        </nav>    
    </header>
    <!-- header End -->

        {% block content %}
            <h1>This is content</h1>
            {% placeholder first_fold %}
            
            {% placeholder proudly_contributing %}
            
            {% placeholder hot_to_use %}

            {% placeholder choose_us %}
            
            {% placeholder our_services %}
            
            {% placeholder our_portfolio %}
        {% endblock content %}

        {% block footer %}
            <h1>This is footer</h1>
            {% static_placeholder footer %}
        {% endblock footer %}
</body>
```

I have added https://github.com/django-cms/djangocms-snippet in each of the placeholder and each `djangocms-snippet` contains a corresponding HTML. That html contains django `static` tag and each of the placehloder prints similar error below.

`Invalid block tag on line 25: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

***Though the same HTML works well if put directly inside the template.***

**Also, if I add `{% load static %}` in each of the snippets, it works.**

Thank for your help in advance.

This is my second djangoCMS-based application and I have compared it with the one working.

Besides, I verified the following settings

```
STATIC_URL
STATIC_URL
STATICFILES_FINDERS
STATIC_ROOT

TEMPLATES
    DIRS
    APP_DIRS
    OPTIONS
        context_processors

CMS_TEMPLATES
MIDDLEWARE
INSTALLED_APPS

DJANGOCMS_SNIPPET_SEARCH 
DJANGOCMS_SNIPPET_THEME
DJANGOCMS_SNIPPET_MODE
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some static reference in base.html

shift this line `{% load static %}` to base.html. this will fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I did not give `base.html` code.  Though `base.html` includes `{% load static %}.

Comment: As you mentioned that static is already loaded in base.html. I think somewhere static is used before is loaded in base.html. you can try to start your base.html like this <!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

Comment: Yes, it is formed correctly. All other static references work as expected. Only those inside `djangocms-snippet` plugin don't work.